# Does SPFx colors affect the SharePoint Site theme

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, sitepages, office-ui-fabric

I have SPFx extensions and webparts deployed in the sites and both framework uses the custom color built in the .sppkg package. And I have custom site theme installed using PowerShell.

Does the SPFx color scheme affect the SharePoint custom/inbuilt theme? As of now, I see the difference when I select the dark blue site theme. The SharePoint site pages and webparts are showing blue and white colors.